# How to get this pair of <h4> text appear side by side?

Tags: html

I would like to place 2 blocks of `<h4>` text side by side. However, the code below places them one on top of the other.

```
<h4><b>name</b> : {{name}} </h4> &nbsp; &nbsp; <h4> <b>number</b> : {{number}} </h4>
```

How should the html code look like to place them side by side without using css? I tried googling but the solutions use css. I do not mind using bootstrap. It will be nice if bootstrap has some quick way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: you have to define the width and the float of the `<h4>` tag without which you can't make them appear side by side. As per the default setting of the `<h4>` tag they take the full width of the parent tag. if you have multiple `<h4>` tag you can define a class `<h4 class='nameOfClass'>` .

Comment: I am using bootstrap. I think bootstrap already defined it for me. I am not sure as I am still new to html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way in HTML, without CSS, is to use a table:

```
<table>
   <tr><td><h4><b>name</b> : {{name}} </h4>
       <td><h4><b>number</b> : {{number}} </h4>
</table>
```

Whether this makes sense is a different issue. A heading should be a heading *for something*, and it is difficult to see what that might be. Probably you should use completely different markup.

Comment: Thanks. I am using bootstrap. Would you know if there are quick ways to solve this problem using bootstrap? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3293156, without context and without an explanation of why you would using heading elements (what would they be headings for?), it is impossible to tell what should be done.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using bootstrap you can use it like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"><h4><b>name</b> : {{name}} </h4></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"><h4><b>number</b> : {{number}} </h4></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using table on your html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Name:</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Number:</h4></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```